# How to resolve this HTML spacing issue?

Tags: html, css

I have no clue where I went wrong. I want to make a grid like responsive image gallery that spans 4 image vertically. The problem I'm having is that when I do so I get this weird white space on the right side of the screen.

I'm thinking it has something to do with image size or maybe I wrote down the wrong code or I'm possibly missing some CSS. If you look at the fiddle and you use the vertical scroll bar and move it right, you'll see that white space. How do I get rid of it? I'll include the code here as well.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg" align="center">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
        <img class="img responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
</div>


<footer id="copy">
<p>Copyright &copy; <i>Minimal Clothing 2017 &reg;</i></p>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper img {
width: 100%;    
}


#copy {
background-color: #161616;
padding: 25px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: auto;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code, try this: set your img to display:block; and let me know if that solves it.

Comment: No it does not unfortunately.

Comment: Can you copy all the code of your webpage, starting at the doc declaration and the <html> tag and ending at the </html> tag so I can copy this and see what is happening?

Comment: @Kobbe can you not access the jsfiddle link?

Comment: Never mind, I copied your code and I do not see that white border. What browser are you using and what version?

Comment: @Michael Coker, I was hoping Gabriel Pozo could save me some time so I did not have to create an html page from scratch and paste the jsfiddle code in the header and the body. But I did. And I am not seeing the border Gabriel is seeing.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ps0zfap8/5/ BOOM!

Comment: @Gabriel Pozo, I notice the class of the second image is missing a dash and is class="img responsive" but should be class="img-responsive" like the other images.

Comment: You've mentioned a fiddle, but it looks like you removed it. Would you either add the fiddle back in, or repair the text please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.row` needs a `.container` parent, otherwise the left/right margins get messed up. Though if you want that `.container` to be full width of the viewport, use `.container-fluid` instead.

Then `.col-*` columns have default padding, so remove that.

```css
#wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}

#copy {
  background-color: #161616;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: white;
}

.col-md-3.nopad {
  padding: 0!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 nopad" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg" align="center">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 nopad" align="center">
        <img class="img responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 nopad" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 nopad" align="center">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<footer id="copy">
  <p>Copyright &copy; <i>Minimal Clothing 2017 &reg;</i></p>
</footer>
```

Comment: This now renders boostraps grid col-md-3 as useless elsewhere where my solution adds an upgrade.

Comment: You have overidden boostrap .col-md-3 {
  padding: 0!important;
}

Comment: It would be better to add an upgrade .gutter-0 .col-md-3

Comment: You are a legend. Thanks again @Michael Coker! :)

Comment: I was just pointing out if you reset, adjust boostrap in the site uses that class elsewhere it may have unexpected results.

Comment: Exactly this solution is not as extravagant as mine. Mine offered a new upgrade that could be applied on any col size across your site.

Comment: My point is simple - your getting upset. You agreed. Not a good idea to over-write bootstrap as we don't know if the OP uses elsewhere. Which we both agree. Apologies if you took offense none meant. Have a good evening.

Comment: Congrats you are in the top 0.1% that is awesome. Seriously!

Answer (score 0):

Add `width : 100%;` to the div with the class `row` and remove its margin `margin: 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has gutter spacing added for cols.
You need to remove the spacing on the cols for this you need the following classes:

CSS

```
 .grid-space-0 {
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 0;
 }

.grid-space-0 {
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
}
.grid-space-0 .col-lg-6,
.grid-space-0 .col-lg-4,
.grid-space-0 .col-lg-3,
.grid-space-0 .col-md-6,
.grid-space-0 .col-md-4,
.grid-space-0 .col-md-3,
.grid-space-0 .col-sm-6,
.grid-space-0 .col-sm-4,
.grid-space-0 .col-sm-3,
.grid-space-0 .col-xs-6,
.grid-space-0 .col-xs-4,
.grid-space-0 .col-xs-3 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
.grid-space-0>div {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

#wrapper {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="row grid-space-0">
    ...
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ps0zfap8/14/

Comment: Yes. This takes care of the spacing but the image protrudes out of the screen by a bit. You can see this by scrolling right. The footer takes up the real space while the image slides out. @MartinWebb

Comment: Add overflow hidden to the outer #wrapper https://jsfiddle.net/ps0zfap8/14/

Comment: In my opinion this is the better solution. It upgrades bootstrap with a new class that will remove the gutter across any col size. It also fixes the OP problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just missed a little bit from its structure which is wrapper class called container and don't forget to include **row** and **grid** (col-sm-* , col-md-* , col-lg-*) class before your own content. Hope this answer your question.

```css
.container-fluid img {
  width: 100%;
}

#copy {
  background-color: #161616;
  padding: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg" align="center">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
      <img class="img responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" align="center">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/8e/c1/28/8ec1283fda885e1854b7dbcbd7b5a353.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <footer id="copy">
        <p>Copyright &copy; <i>Minimal Clothing 2017 &reg;</i></p>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```